# Rails: How to use dependent: :destroy in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 models as describes below.

```
class EmpGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :emp_group_members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class EmpGroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :emp_group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

now the problem is whenever I tried to destroy a group then I received a error as below.

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "emp_groups" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_bd68440021" on table "emp_group_members"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "emp_group_members".
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add cascading delete to your `EmpGroup` model:

```
class EmpGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :emp_group_members, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Or

Are you calling `delete` method? you should call `destroy` instead.
Use `.destroy`

Comment: Note: Using destroy instead of delete is very important because in case the belonging model (in this case: emp_group_member) has further associations or in any case, the destroy method of emp_group_member will not be called and deleting will simply remove the 1st child. If you want the destroy to be cascading till end, add dependent: :destroy.
@Milind 's answer is quite helpful in understanding this point.

Comment: This value `:delete_all` isn't allowed anymore.

Answer (score 32):

[:dependent](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent) is one of the options available in **belongs_to** association

```
If you set the :dependent option to:

:destroy, when the object is destroyed, destroy will be called on its associated objects.
:delete, when the object is destroyed, all its associated objects will be deleted directly from the database without calling their destroy method.
```

`Additionally, objects will be destroyed if they're associated with dependent: :destroy, and deleted if they're associated with dependent:` :delete_all.

**in has_many** associations:

```
:destroy causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed
:delete_all causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not execute)
```

you can try

```
 emp_member_1= @emp_group.emp_group_members.first
 ##delete associated record
 @emp_group.emp_group_members.delete(emp_member_1)
```

Comment: From the documentation: "You should not specify this option on a belongs_to association that is connected with a has_many association on the other class. Doing so can lead to orphaned records in your database." (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent)

Comment: Sure, that's in the documentation, but what does it MEAN?

Comment: They're warning us not to do... something. But it's not clear what that something is. Do I put the `dependent: destroy` on the has_many side, or on the belongs_to side? The whole point of this option is to avoid orphaned records, so why does one of the usages of it cause orphaned records?

Comment: @AndrewKoster, this is the warning -> Doing so can lead to orphaned records in your database -- that means you might delete user but user has_many friends will still be there in the db, thereby creating inconsistencies to hunt to one fine day :).So Logically , if user has_many friends, then along with the user , his friends records should also get deleted, where the above :dependent comes into picture.Hope its clear now.

Comment: The part I don't understand is why they're saying not to use `dependent: destroy` on the belongs_to side. Why do they allow it as an option, if it doesn't work?

Comment: Because  deleting has_many wont have any impact on belongs-to but deleting belongs-to would leave has_many orphaned in db. Hence they say it this way.

Answer (score 17):

New syntax:

```
class EmpGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :emp_group_members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a group, are you using delete or destroy. - I've had this error before, and it was because I had a typo and was using .delete instead of .destroy

Answer (score 0):

Insert relation like this

```
has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
```

To learn more about destroy and delete, go to this link
https://medium.com/@wkhearn/delete-vs-destroy-does-it-even-matter-8cb4db6aa660