# Deleting associated record deletes the original after overriding has_many association getter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to override a `has_many` association getter using a method.

I have a `has_many` association for cards via join table `user_cards`. I added a method into the model... trying to completely override the conditions.

```
has_many :cards, through: :user_cards, source: :canonical, source_type: 'Primary'
```

The `user_cards` is polymorphic so there's a `source` and a `source_type` from the association call.

The getter looks okay... as expected.

```
def cards
  Card.where(id: user_cards.pluck(:card_id))
end
```

However... the simple deletion of associated record(s) is now deleting the original, not just the join table records which is very scary and can destroy the app.

```
@card = Card.find(1)
@user.cards.delete(@card)
```

The above deletes the `@card` object completely from the database... I'm expecting it to delete the `@user.user_cards` record.

I'm not familiar in overriding association getter... Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dependent: :destroy in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560805/how-to-use-dependent-destroy-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to solve this problem is to destroy `UserCard` directly.

```
@card = Card.find(1)
@card.user_cards.where(user_id: @user.id).destroy
```

But ensure that `UserCard` does not have `dependent: destroy`