# ruby on rails Nested structure not deleting the related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, destroy

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, allow_destroy: true
end
```

post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true
end
```

user controller

```
class Api::UsersController < ApiController
  def destroy
    User.destroy(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I thought if I destroy the user using destroy, all the posts related to user will be deleted automatically.

But still nothing is deleted.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, check this post please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560805/how-to-use-dependent-destroy-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dependent: :delete_all`

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Comment: dumping code without any explanation is not a really good format for an answer