# RoR associations: has_one + has_many depedent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-many

I don't get why I'm having orphans records when I try to destroy a user. A **User** *has one* **Cart** which *has many* **CartItem**

---

**User has one cart:**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cart, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cart_items, through: :cart, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :samples, through: :cart_items, source: :cartable, source_type: 'Sample'
  has_many :tracks, through: :cart_items, source: :cartable, source_type: 'Track'
end
```

> :dependent
>
> Controls what happens to the associated object when its owner is destroyed:
>
> - :destroy causes the associated object to also be destroyed
>
> https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

**Cart has many items:**

```rb
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cart_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :samples, through: :cart_items, source: :cartable, source_type: 'Sample'
  has_many :tracks, through: :cart_items, source: :cartable, source_type: 'Track'
end
```

> :dependent
>
> Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed. Note that these are implemented as callbacks, and Rails
>   executes callbacks in order. Therefore, other similar callbacks may
>   affect the :dependent behavior, and the :dependent behavior may affect
>   other callbacks.
>
> - :destroy causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.
>
> https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

**And items:**

```rb
class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :cartable, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

I'd like to be able to destroy a User with  for example `User.last.destroy`, but instead I've an error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_ea59a35211" on table "carts"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(227) is still referenced from table "carts".
```

---

I was thinking that `has_one :cart, dependent: :destroy` would do the job but it looks like I'm wrong. What am I missing ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What is `Cart.where(user_id: 227).count`? Perhaps you've managed to create multiple carts for one user, and that's messing up the database integrity. If you delete all "duplicate" carts, you could add a validation or even a unique index database constraint, to prevent it happening again.

Comment: Indeed ! I have no idea how this happens tho (this is how I was crowding my Cart model: `10.times { |i| Cart.create!(user_id: User.all[i].id) }`. I've added a reference to cart to the users db, thanks for the debug and the advises :)

Comment: What database ur using?

Comment: PostgreSQL, why that ?

Comment: If you're using the `rails console`, try `reload!`ing it in case you're not working with the latest code. If you're sure you're working with the latest code, try isolating the issue to a minimal user with just 1 cart and 1 cart_item, and try deleting it. If you're able to delete that new specific user, there's most likely a database inconsistency.

Comment: I got your error when doing `Model.find(1).delete` however `Model.find(1).destroy` worked. Are you sure you're using `destroy` and not `delete`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dependent: :destroy in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560805/how-to-use-dependent-destroy-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem on my development machine, then I found root cause of this issue after lot of debugging and analysis. Postgres was creating extra constraints which was causing this.
You need to drop the constraints. You can do this by a migration.

```
rails g migration remove_fk_constraints

class RemoveFkConstrains < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute "ALTER TABLE carts DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_ea59a35211;"
  end
end
```

Comment: I just tried this and you're right if one uses `Model.find(1).delete` this error message shows, however `Model.find(1).destroy` works as advertised